# Rails 5 capistrano deploy not picking up new changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, web-deployment, unicorn, capistrano3

I have a Rails 5 app, for some reason after a few first deployments the app stop picking up the changes, I'm using capistrano 3, nginx, unicorn, de deploy flow run perfect with no error output, I checked de releases, the current folder even and the code is there, but in the browser I keep seeing an old version, a version by the way that is not longer in the 5 max releases that capistrano save, I don't know how to ckeck if all the gems have the proper version as someone told me it could be a reason. Any information extra please ask.

Comment: Is the `current` symlink changing when you deploy to a new location?

Comment: Yes after every deploy current points to the last release made by capistrano, I just cheked with the last release.

Comment: If you manually restart your rails server, does it pick up the new release?

Comment: Nop after every deploy I go and write sudo service nginx restart and it does restart but not new changes

Comment: IIRC, Unicorn is running on a different port and nginx is just reverse proxying. So restarting nginx will not make a difference. Is Unicorn being restarted after a deploy?